# String.Split() method: compiler chooses wrong overload

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
using System;

class Token
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter string to tokenize: ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nString length: {0}\n\nTokens:", s.Length);
        string[] tok = s.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //<-- this line causes CS1503
        //string[] tok = s.Split(); //works but also returns empty entries
        foreach (string i in tok)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
        Console.Write("\n{0} tokens found\nPress any key to continue . . . ", tok.Length);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to take a string from the console input and split it into tokens (separated by spaces). I am using the `String.Split()` method. By default, this method returns all the empty tokens (if there are multiple consecutive separators), which is something I don't want. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) this method has a bunch of overloads. The default `String.Split()` with no parameters calls this overload:

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator);
```

There is an overload which doesn't return the empty tokens:

```
public string[] Split(char separator, StringSplitOptions options = System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

From what I understand, in order to make it not return empty tokens, the second parameter has to be `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. So the intuitive way to call this is:

```
s.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The compiler, however, thinks otherwise, and throws error CS1503 at me:

```
CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char'
```

So it's obvious that the compiler is not choosing the overload I want. Hovering over the function calls makes IntelliSense show me this:

```
string[] Split(params char[] separator)
```

How should I call `String.Split()` in order to call the overload I want?

Comment: The linked article is for .net core.  Just to confirm, is that the project you are targeting?

Comment: First parameter is a `char[]`, -> `s.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: `Split(char, StringSplitOptions)` was introduced in .NET Core 2.0. Before then, the best overload was `Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)`, which you would call as `s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. What are you targeting?

Comment: I thought that .net core is just a basic set of .net framework available on more platforms. Shouldn't it compile in windows (.net framework 4.7.2)?

Comment: You're thinking of [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), I think (which defines a set of APIs available on multiple platforms). .NET Core is effectively a new (well, not that new any more) rewritten runtime which supersedes .NET Framework, while also targeting more platforms. A lot of stuff has been introduced in .NET Core since the last version of .NET Framework was released. It's getting rebranded to .NET 5 in the next release.

Comment: When viewing the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2), make sure to select the appropriate version under the "Version" combobox in the top left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET Framework use

```
char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ' ' };
string[] tok = s.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In NET core (I test in 2.2). the code is working